# Unknown database issue after re-installing wamp server

Tags: laravel-5, wampserver

After having trouble with wamp server, i've uninstalled it and made a mistake by moving the www folder and download wamp all over again.

So after installing wamp and fixing the problem i had, my project (using laravel) doesn't work anymore:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db_name'
```

I tried `php artisan cache:clear` but nothing changed

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Laravel can't find a database. Maybe you forgot to restore your database(s)? The thing is with uninstalling WAMP, you have deleted MySQL with all databases (M in WAMP stands for MySQL).

Or maybe you forgot to setup DB host, user and password in .env file.

Comment: Can i restore them now or is it too late?

Comment: If you did not do backup, no. There is a tiny chance: restore erased mysql  files with Recuva or similar tool and try to use them. But if you're not familiar with all that stuff, you have no chances, sorry. You should always do data backups. If you didn't have a lot of data there, you can run migrations again (if you used them) to restore DB structure. Or you could recreate database with all the tables and data manually.

Comment: First, read about how to restore database after unistalled MySQL (what files you need to do that, steps etc). Then use Recuva to recover deleted files. Good luck. )